# Can dropzone.js allow image cropping and rotating before upload?

Tags: dropzone.js

I have the uploading and previewing working just fine but sometimes the images are sideways or need to be cropped. If not maybe it can work with in conjunction with another library?

This site mentioned that it could:
https://colorlib.com/wp/jquery-file-upload-scripts/#comment-621899